# Drawing a line while moving the mouse and holding the right-click button

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to draw a line on the panel as I move my mouse while holding the right-click button. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    Point cordinatedClikedPoint = new Point(xPanelPosition, yPanelPositon);
    DrawPoint((point.X), (point.Y), Color.Navy);                
}

public void DrawPoint(int x, int y, Color color)
{
    Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();
    Pen pen = new Pen(color);
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, 3, 3);
}
```

Comment: Please tag this question, WinForms, or WPF, or Whatever.  C# alone does not draw lines.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `PointToClient(Cursor.Location)` rather than the `e.Location` provided by the `MouseEventArgs`?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events to set a bool variable, do your drawing in your `MouseMove` EventHandler. Since you are calling the graphic object directly any invalidation or repaint operation on the panel will cause it to be cleared, the other two answers address that.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool mouseIsDown;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button== System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            mouseIsDown = true;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseIsDown)
        {
            Point point = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            DrawPoint((point.X), (point.Y), Color.Navy);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseIsDown = false;
    }

    public void DrawPoint(int x, int y, Color color)
    {
        Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(color);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, 3, 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another one...this time using ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine():

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Point StartPoint, EndPoint;

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Point pt = Cursor.Position;
            StartPoint = pt;
            EndPoint = pt;
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(StartPoint, EndPoint, Color.Black);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(StartPoint, EndPoint, Color.Black); // erase previous line
            EndPoint = Cursor.Position;
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(StartPoint, EndPoint, Color.Black); // draw new line
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(StartPoint, EndPoint, Color.Black); // erase previous line

            // ... do something with StartPont and EndPoint in here ...

            // possibly add them to a class level structure to use in the Paint() event to make it persistent?

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to invalidate the panel on every draw.

```
private IList<Point> _pointList = new List<Point>();
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
    _pointList.Add( e.Location );
    panel1.Invalidate(); //force a repaint
}

private void panel1_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLines( Pens.Black, _pointList );
}
```

Comment: thanks you Mayank,but e.Graphics.DrawLines( Pens.Black, _pointList );does not accept list as its second argument and it complains that it can not convert system.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Point> to System.Drawing.Point[]

Comment: just call `ToArray()` to convert it to array

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a complete solution of what you are trying to do:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Graphics g;
    private readonly Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 7);
    private Point oldCoords;
    private readonly GraphicsPath graphicsPaths = new GraphicsPath();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (oldCoords.IsEmpty)
                graphicsPaths.StartFigure();
            else
            {
                graphicsPaths.AddLine(oldCoords, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                g.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPaths);
            }
            oldCoords= new Point(e.X,e.Y);
        }
        else
            oldCoords = Point.Empty;
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPaths);
    }
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Btw.. if you want to react to right mouse button instead of left just change the line to: if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know MouseDown event fires one-time when you push the button. And WindowsForms panel/form or whatever there is is redrawn every few ms. Therefore you need to put that code into `OnPaint` method instead.

It should look something like that:

```
//global variable
bool isDragging = false;

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
            isDragging = true;               
}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
            isDragging = false;               
}

private void form_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if(isDragging)
            {
               Point point = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
               Point cordinatedClikedPoint = new Point(xPanelPosition, yPanelPositon);
               DrawPoint((point.X), (point.Y), Color.Navy);
            }
}
```